# Adding results from search into a table in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I did a search with Python and got the result below but having troubles saving it to a table in SQLite. Table having 3 Columns (category, name, id)

### Code:

```
data = [{u'category': u'Local Business',
       u'category_list': [{u'id': u'145887745471348', u'name': u'Train Station'}],
       u'id': u'129926257075048',
       u'name': u'Southampton the Fit Student Central!'},
      {u'category': u'Local Business',
       u'category_list': [{u'id': u'2500', u'name': u'Local Business'}],
       u'id': u'151910741511395',
       u'name': u'Student Hell Train'},
      {u'category': u'Local Business',
       u'category_list': [{u'id': u'192119584190796', u'name': u'Event'}],
       u'id': u'159561157587886',
       u'name': u'Student Ambassador Training'}]


    stmt = "insert into Student_Mentors (category, name, id) values ({category}, {name}, {id})".format(**data)
    con.executemany(stmt, data)
    con.commit()
```

I get the following error...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-58d2f1a67f61> in <module>()
     13 
     14 
---> 15 stmt = "insert into Student_Mentors (category, name, id) values ({category}, {name}, {id})".format(**data)
     16 con.executemany(stmt, data)
     17 con.commit()

TypeError: format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
```

Not sure how to make it a mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module's [`paramstyle`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) is `qmark` meaning placeholder for parameters should be `?`s.

You need to use like below:

```
stmt = "INSERT INTO Student_Mentors (category, name, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
rows = [[row['category'], row['name'], row['id']] for row in data]
con.executemany(stmt, rows)
con.commit()
```

Comment: That completely makes sense and does work. Thanks for pointing that out.